# Bootable USB won't boot

Tags: system-installation, release-juno

I'm very excited about getting Juno installed, but unfortunately, after creating a bootable USB-drive with unetbootin and booting the drive, I stare at nothing but a black screen. It doesn't matter which option I choose, it always has the same result. I tried redownloading the .iso-file. Different USB-drives and different USB-slots on the laptop, but still it won't boot. Can anyone help me? I have a Korora Penguin laptop from ThinkPenguin, which never had any problems booting any Linux system before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I flashed my usb with [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) and everything went smooth. Give it a try.

Comment: I used etcher to burn the USB-drive and that worked fine. It's a shame that the official instructions on the website don't work for me. I wonder if I should file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar post with an identical problem. It was solved by turning of the `Secure Boot` option in the BIOS. As I know `Secure Boot` checks the boot drive for a signature to make sure nothing suspicious is being booted. By turning it off you skip that.

Comment: I tried that, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have windows? you should use rufus and take mode UEFI on rufus or you can search elementary market Image Writer I tried and this is working good.

And you don't have windows then you can install wine and try run rufus.

Answer (score 0):

1- burn elementary OS in USB.

2- Reboot your pc, Press F12 OR F9 (BOOT mode) then

choose FROM  UEFI BOOT:

UEFI: INT13 (USB,0x80)

3- After installing, You need to BOOT from UEFI BOOT : ubuntu.